# Why does println!(foo.bar()?) move foo?

Tags: rust

Definition of bar():

```rust
pub fn bar(self) -> Result<String>
```

The compiler gives me an error:

```
println!("{}", foo.bar()?);
let deserialized = serde_json::from_str(&foo.bar()?)?; // Use of 'foo' after move
```

Why does the `println` move `foo`?  When I bind another variable to `foo.bar()`, the compiler is fine.

EDIT: here's basically what I've got

```
let res = reqwest::blocking::get(request_path)?;
println!("{}", res.text()?);
                   ------ `res` moved due to this method call
let deserialized = serde_json::from_str(&res.text()?)?;
                                         ^^^ value used here after move
```

Comment: It looks to me like it's the first call to `bar()` that took ownership of `foo` and didn't give it back, unrelated to `println!`.  What's the complete code that worked?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes you think println is doing the move? `bar` explicitly states it moves; you'd get the same error in:

```
let x = foo.bar()?;
let y = foo.bar()?;  // Error, foo has been moved.
```

> When I bind another variable to foo.bar(), the compiler is fine.

Because now you're no longer trying to use `foo` again. Instead, you're reusing the return value from the call multiple times which is fine (that is, until *it* is moved!).

Comment: "bar explicitly states it moves"


What part of the function signature tells you this?  I added a snippet of what I'm doing, and the signature of `res.text()` is `pub fn text(self) -> crate::Result<String>`.  I thought the `String` in `Result<>` meant the returned value took ownership of the text or a copy of it.

Comment: @Jerry the `self`, that means it takes `self: Self`, aka takes the subject by value. `&self` would be `self: &Self` aka taking the subject by shared reference, and `&mut self` would be `self: &mut Self` aka taking the subject by unique reference.